# Xamarin.forms webview and view/play video in HTML5 video tag and android issue

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I am capturing video using `MediaPicker` from `xamarin.labs` and then upload that video on my web server. Then after, I retrieve that video to show in WebView with HTML5 video tag.

This works fine for iOS. however the same code doesn't work on Android.

I create custom renderer in android to create `Webchromeclient` but it does not play video on android.

the sample html5 with video is (I also try with `type` parameter in `<video>` tag:

```
<Doctype! HTML>
<html>
<body><video src="www.myserver.com/video1.mp4" controls height="150" width="150"/>
</body>
</html/>
```

and this is my web view part in my PCL project:

```
public class MyWebView: WebView
{
}
```

this is my page:

```
public class VideoPage: ContentPage
{
   public VidoePage()
   {
      var webView = new MyWebView();
      webView.Source = new HtmlSource {Html = abovementionedHtml};
      var layout = new StackLayout()
     {
        Childern = {webWiew}
     };
     this.Content= layout;
}
```

Android renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))] 
namespace VideoSample.Droid
{

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebRenderer 
{
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs  e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new global::Android.Webkit.WebView(this.Context);
            webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
            this.SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
    }    
}
}
```

So can anyone tell me what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the sample HTML as below with some fixes. Not sure if this is the 
root cause.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <video src="http://www.myserver.com/video1.mp4" controls height="150" width="150">
</body>
</html>
```

I made the adjustments for two things:

- The DOCTYPE
- Adding "http://" at the beginning of the URL

Also, you may refer to [this blog post (Making HTML5 Video work on Android phones)](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) for further HTML tips and tricks on making video work.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Lau, I already have "http://" in my html and <DocType HTML> is correct in  my code, it was just typo here. Actually, I already referred your blog twice, and follows the instructions mentioned. but still I am not succeed in android. However I don't apply javascript as of now. as it is not required i guess.